# How do you use the /testfor command in 1.5.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I play in 1.5.2, and right now I'm working on using commands. I see that there's a /testfor command when I write /help, but what does this even mean? What is it and how do I use it?
Edit: This question is not a copy: 1.5.2 commands could very possibly be different than the latest version.

Comment: It could very well be, but is it? If you want to differentiate between the two questions, please do so with solid argumentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[/testfor](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/testfor), in a command block paired with a comparator, counts how many entities match specified conditions. For instance, `testfor Unionhawk` will emit a signal if I am online. `testfor @a[x=0,y=64,z=0,r=3,m=0]` counts the number of players within 3 blocks of 0,64,0.

In general, `/testfor` is not particularly useful. Most of the time you will want to use scoreboard commands to work with entities matching desired criteria, since you can use scores in other commands.